# Adaptive filter weight adjustment

Tags: adaptive-filters, adaptive-algorithms

I have 3 sensor inputs: $a(t)$, $b(t)$ and $c(t)$. I want to design a filter such that the weighted linear combination of the three is always a constant. Kind of like:

$$w_1(t)a(t) + w_2(t)b(t) + w_3(t)c(t) = k$$

So from my undergrad modules I think I need a adaptive filters. I can perform training to find $k$ and filter weights at initialization.

May I know what is the best filter to implement in my case? $a(t)$, $b(t)$ and $c(t)$ are not independent.

Kelvin

Comment: You need more definition of what you're trying to achieve. There are many solutions to your problem. For instance, $w_1(t) = 0, w_2(t) = 0, w_3(t) = \frac{k}{c(t)}$ is a perfectly acceptable solution according to the details you've given thus far, but I doubt it does what you want.

Comment: Hey Jason thanks alot. How about setting a non zero and non negative constraint on the filter weights? Would that be sufficient?

Comment: That's not exactly what I had in mind. There are going to be many solutions to your problem, but you need to pick the one that will give you the eventual *effect* that you need in your system. Adaptive filters typically tune their filter weights to meet some optimization criterion. I think your constraint is a bit weak for that objective. What is your system supposed to do?

Comment: Ok let me try again. What I want to achieve is to find filter weights $w_1(t), w_2(t), w_3(t)$ such that the linear weighted combination of $a(t)$, $b(t)$ and $c(t)$ is always a constant value $k$. This is part of a bigger system. I have a perfect estimation of the initial filter weights and also the constant. And the filter weights will not swing too much from one time instant to another. The constant $k$ is not time dependent.

Comment: If you know $k$, look up LMS, Least-Mean-Squares filter, e.g. [how-to-apply-an-adaptive-filter-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252160/how-to-apply-an-adaptive-filter-in-python) on SO. If you don't, maybe 4  weights(t) with target 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was getting at in the comments above is that the linear system $w_1(t)a(t) + w_2(t)b(t) + w_3(t)c(t) = k$ has an infinite number of solutions, so you need to state some criterion that allows you to choose a unique solution. I think you have pointed out a constraint that is worth examining.

The idea: note that the linear equation I gave above is the [equation for a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29#Point-normal_form_and_general_form_of_the_equation_of_a_plane):

$$w_1(t)a(t) + w_2(t)b(t) + w_3(t)c(t) = k$$

- This defines a plane in three-dimensional Euclidean space.
- $\left[a(t), b(t), c(t) \right]$ is a vector that is normal to the plane.
- The collection of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the form $\left[w_1(t),\ w_2(t),\ w_3(t)\right]$that satisfy the above equation are points on the plane.
- Since you said that $w_1(t), w_2(t), w_3(t)$ don't change much over a short time duration, then you can assume that the point $\left[w_1(t+\Delta t),\ w_2(t+\Delta t),\ w_3(t+\Delta t)\right]$ should be geometrically close to the point at the previous time instant, $\left[w_1(t),\ w_2(t),\ w_3(t)\right]$.

So, the algorithm would look something like this:

- Initialize your algorithm by finding $k$, which you said you can do.
- Solve for the initial weights $w_1(t), w_2(t), w_3(t)$, which you said you can do.
- On subsequent time steps, measure $a(t)$, $b(t)$, and $c(t)$. This defines the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that the filter weight vector can possibly lie upon.
- Find the point on the plane that is closest to the filter weights from the previous iteration. Use this point as the new vector of filter weights.
- Repeat.

I'm not sure if this will give the desired effect or not (as your inquiry is light on details), but it has an intuitive geometric explanation. It might be worth a try.

Comment: Hi Jason thanks for answer.  Now I understand what you mean by limited detail. The solution is not unique. I will go back to the drawing board again to see what other constraint I can set so that I can get a unique solution.

Comment: Basically there must be a constraint on the inputs. For a general case as mentioned in the question it seems weights wont converge. For a simple example when the inputs are dc, solution becomes trivial.